# Prove the following automorphism exists

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Having a field $ℚ(x_1, ... , x_n)/ℚ$, where $x_1, ... , x_n$ are the roots of a polynomial (although I'm not sure if that is of any importance to my question), does there exists a bijection for every permutation $σ$ of $x_1, ... , x_n$ from $ℚ(x_1, ... , x_n)/ℚ$ into itself?

It is supposed to be that way, at least that is what I understand from a sentence of a text. It is supposed to be "obvious".

The issue is that I'm not entirely sure that it is impossible for a given permutation $σ$ to map two different elements of $ℚ(x_1, ... , x_n)/ℚ$ into the same place.

How could one prove that this is never the case?

Any help/thoughts would be rrally appreciated.

Comment: The inverse of $\sigma$ should also give rise to a map from $\mathbb{Q}(x_1, \dots, x_n)/\mathbb{Q}$ to itself. I guess they should be inverse to each other. (But it's a long time ago that I studied that subject, so I'm not sure any more when permutations extend in this way.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no: there is a basic result in [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Modern_approach_by_field_theory) like that. It's mentioned at this link, at least, the formulation I think you want, which is that every permutation of roots of an irreducible polynomial gives rise to an automorphism of the splitting field of the polynomial.

See [lemma 18.3 in Isaacs *Graduate Algebra*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5tKq0kbHuc4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=isaacs+graduate+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPuMCqsLHWAhXI5yYKHf6aDHsQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=18.3%20LEMMA&f=false) for example.

Comment: The assumption that the polynomial is irreducible is *not* made by the OP, so their statement is false. (Counterexample $\mathbb Q(0,1)/\mathbb Q$.)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Yes... Hopefully pointing them to this set of hypotheses is rather what they needed than what they asked for.